# Easy way to Populate a Dictionary<string,List<string>>

Tags: c#, linq

Greetings Guru's, my objective is to create a Dictionary of Lists, does a simpler technique exist?

I prefer the List(t) to IEnumerable(t) which is why I chose the Dictionary of Lists over Ilookup or IGrouping.

The code works but it seems like a messy way of doing things.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles (@"C:\test");

Dictionary<string,List<string>> DataX = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();

foreach (var group in files.GroupBy (file => Path.GetExtension (file)))
{
   DataX.Add (group.Key, group.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this question be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it. Why do you think it's *messy*?

Comment: @Klaus: I thought he was rather spoiled as well, but the Linq implementation does look a lot cleaner. @Zion: You seem to have the right mindset to give F# a try, that's all about being clean.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To do it all in LINQ you can use [`ToDictionary()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx):

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles (@"C:\test");
var DataX = files.GroupBy (file => Path.GetExtension (file))
                 .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

or as Klaus points below out you can do this all in one go:

```
var DataX = Directory.GetFiles (@"C:\test")
                 .GroupBy (file => Path.GetExtension (file))
                 .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Comment: +1, why not remove the declaration of `files` while you are at it.

Comment: @Klaus True, thanks - edited in. I'm not a big fan of compressing everything down too much as it makes it harder to step through and debug (and can make it less readable too) but I can't see any issues doing that here.

Comment: @diceguyd30 heh, sorry. Happens to me a lot too.